# data types and their comparsions in php

Tags: php

im not very experienced in php. The problem i'm facing is:

```
print "post: {$_POST['var']} session: {$_SESSION['var']}\n";
```

let's say this prints 2 equal outputs.

then

```
if($_POST['var'] == $_SESSION['var']){
...
}
```

never evaluates as true. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you copy exactly what it outputs and put it on here?

Comment: What exactly does it print out? Did you look at it with an hexeditor? Just because it appears the same doesn't mean there isn't any extra space or NUL byte in either.

Comment: Like @mario said, there could for instant be whitespaces on either side of the `var` so you comparision never returns true. Try running `trim` on both the `$_SESSION['var']` and the `$_POST['var']`.

Comment: @mario you're right if I put there a dot after each of the variables and by post there is some whitespace in between

Comment: @Krister Andersson: yup thanks, trim saves the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if (trim($_POST['var']) == trim($_SESSION['var'])) {
  // ...
}
```

You could also check the contents of the `$_SESSION['var']` and `$_POST['var']` using `var_dump` and see if they match:

```
var_dump($_POST['var']);
var_dump($_SESSION['var']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is likely to be a data type issue (unless they are floating point numbers then it may be) but if you want to check if they are the same type then use ===.  My guess would be that there is a rouge space in one of them that you can't detect when you print it out.  Can you give the example of what gets printed out?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$_SESSION['var'] = "Variable";
$_POST['var'] = "Variable";

if($_POST['var'] == $_SESSION['var'])
    print 1;
else
    print 2;

?>
```

Result is 1. What are the values of the variables you compare ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a data type issue but if you do want to compare data types in php you can do the following:

```
if($_POST['var'] === $_SESSION['var']){
    ...
}
```

alternatively you can cast data types by doing the following: (int) (array) (object)

```
$a = (int)$_POST['var'];
$b = (int)$_SESSION['var'];

if($a === $b) {
    ...
}
```